# Python filter a list of dictionaries by another dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

I have the below list of dictionaries & a dictionary,
I want to return the person name if there's a match

```py
mydblist = [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},{'name': 'Bob', 'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},{'name': 'Charlie', 'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}]

dna_dict = {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}
```

so now I need to print name 'Bob' from the list of dictionaries mydict_list , as he has a full match with dna_dict,

or print no match in case no match found

Many thanks for your support in advance

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is not a coding service: we expect you to make an honest attempt to post.

Comment: thank you sir for your instructions, I actually learning how to code , I am not a programmer , 
I'll go through the how to ask link you provided, I apologize for the in convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the list provided I wrote the solution below. It's just compare the dict keys. One dict has a str type and other with int type that's why the code convert the type.

```py
def compare_dicts(a, b):
    """
    Compare all keys of A with the same key in B
    """

    for key in a.keys():
        if key in b:

            if a[key] != int(b[key]):
                return False

    return True

for dict_obj in mydblist:
    if compare_dicts(dna_dict, dict_obj):
        print(dict_obj['name'])
```

Comment: Many thanks sir , this is perfect
I have a question please, what do you recommend for my to study programming , I'm actually new in this , and really eager to learn

Comment: My main source is the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Maybe that seems a bit scary but have a lot of code examples there and a rich text. I think that spend some time reading what you need in that docs can help you grow.

Comment: and I have modified my results to make both values strings , for ease of comparison

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 mydblist = [{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'},{'name': 'Bob', 'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'},{'name': 'Charlie', 'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}]

 # Here i changed dna_dict value integer to string
 dna_dict = {'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}

    for i in mydblist:
        if i["AGATC"] == dna_dict["AGATC"] and i["AATG"] == dna_dict["AATG"] and i["TATC"] == dna_dict["TATC"]:
            print(i["name"])
```

Comment: thank you sir, I have found it working , but not dynamically can change variables , the code above is best suite my needs ,, I appreciate it